# Sorting a list of items with underscores

Tags: itemize, sorting

I am trying to alphabetically sort a bunch of items (for a coding base), and naturally many of the method names have underscores. Normally I can sort any number of items in LaTeX using a sortedlist without any problems, but it appears that if an item is identical up to an underscore, then LaTeX throws an error associated with infinitely looping

```
"! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]."
```

Below is my document

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[amssymb]{SIunits}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{datatool}

\parindent=10pt
\hoffset=0pt
\voffset=0pt
\oddsidemargin=0.5in
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth-2.5in-\oddsidemargin}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,array,longtable,delarray,verbatim,epsfig}
%\graphicspath{{Macintosh HD\Users\Luke\Google Drive\Triton\Procedures}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\LN}{$\mathrm{LN_2}$~}
\newcommand{\HeThree}{$\mathrm{^3He}$~}
\newcommand{\sortitem}[1]{%
  \DTLnewrow{list}% Create a new entry
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#1}% Add entry as description
}
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}% Create new/discard old list
}{%
  \DTLsort{description}{list}% Sort list
  \begin{itemize}%
    \DTLforeach*{list}{\theDesc=description}{%
      \item \theDesc}% Print each item
  \end{itemize}%
}

\begin{sortedlist}
  \sortitem{gauss\_cf2()}
  \sortitem{lorenzian\_cf()}
  \sortitem{linear\_cf()}
  \sortitem{eq\_lorentz()}
  \sortitem{eq\_linear()}
\end{sortedlist}

\end{document}
```

If I remove the last item, it compiles fine. So it appears that it can deal with underscores just fine, however it can't seem to sort if items are identical up to an underscore.

Does anybody know a way around this? This would be very convenient for our documentation database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an entry where the underscore is removed:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[amssymb]{SIunits}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\parindent=10pt
\hoffset=0pt
\voffset=0pt
\oddsidemargin=0.5in
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth-2.5in-\oddsidemargin}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,array,longtable,delarray,verbatim,epsfig}
%\graphicspath{{Macintosh HD\Users\Luke\Google Drive\Triton\Procedures}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\LN}{$\mathrm{LN_2}$~}
\newcommand{\HeThree}{$\mathrm{^3He}$~}
\newcommand{\sortitem}[1]{%
  \DTLnewrow{list}% Create a new entry
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#1}% Add entry as description
  \begingroup
  \def\_{}%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\DTLnewdbentry{list}{no-us-description}{#1}}\x
}
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{%
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}% Create new/discard old list
}{%
  \DTLsort{no-us-description}{list}% Sort list
  \begin{itemize}%
    \DTLforeach*{list}{\theDesc=description}{%
      \item \theDesc}% Print each item
  \end{itemize}%
}

\begin{sortedlist}
  \sortitem{gauss\_cf2()}
  \sortitem{lorenzian\_cf()}
  \sortitem{linear\_cf()}
  \sortitem{eq\_lorentz()}
  \sortitem{eq\_linear()}
\end{sortedlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]